# DCM4CHEE Linux/Oracle installation

Tags: java, oracle, dcm4che

I'm new to PACS and Dcm4chee installation.
I try to install DCM4CHEE but I get some error on startup/login (
dcm4che2.18+dcm4chee-arr-3.0.12 , Linux , Oracle DB)

- when I startup JBoss into server.log i see this message

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: code_version in
>   ARR.CODE

I'm looking for DDL of table CODE and I saw that the column is defined in create.ora (dcm4che2.17) but not in create.ddl (dcm4chee-arr-3.0.12)

- If I login to dcm4chee-web3 (http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-web3/) on server.log I get this message

> 2015-04-20 16:03:41,764 WARN  -> (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1)
>   [org.dcm4chee.web.common.license.ae.AELicenseProviderManager] No
>   AELicenseProvider found for name: null
>       2015-04-20 16:03:41,939 ERROR -> (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) [org.dcm4chee.web.common.secure.SecureTab] Can't instantiate Panel for
>   panel
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Which version is recommended? Dcm4che 2.18+JBoss 4.2.3 (old) or Dcm4che 3.x+JBossAS7. On internet I found a lot of documentation on 2.17 installation, but none on 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you follow step 5 in http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Installation particularly editing the deploy/arr-xxx-ds.xml file.

For versions, use DCM4CHEE 2.17 or 2.18 + JBoss 4.2.3.

DCM4CHE 3 is a toolkit 
DCM4CHEE 4 is the new archive that will work with new versions of JBoss, but is not as fully functional as DCM4CHEE 2.

(FYI, 1 E is toolkit, 2 E's is an archive)